# @Configuration @ImportResource with FileSystemResource reading properties from Web-Inf

Tags: spring, configuration

I am trying to read a properties file from WEB-INF using Java-based Configuration of my Spring MVC app. I can make this work when I put the properties directory in the src directory and use class: (ClassPathResource).

I want to use @ImportResource with file: (FileSystemResource) that will read from properties/ or resources/properties/ or /properties/ or /resources/properties/ when this is located in WebContent or WEB-INF

When I use file: I get a FileNotFoundException.

I have tried moving the properties directory around and used @ImportResource with "file:/properties/properties-config.xml", "file:/WebContent/properties/properties-config.xml", and /WEB-INF/properties/properties-config.xml".

I mapped  in my app-servlet.xml and tried "file:/resources/properties/properties-config.xml"

This should be straightforward and not uncommon. But I can't find an example of getting properties files this way.

```
@ImportResource("file:/properties/properties-config.xml")
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

private @Value("#{v1Properties['v1.dataUrl']}") String dataUrl;
private @Value("#{v1Properties['v1.metaUrl']}") String metaUrl;
private @Value("#{v1Properties['v1.user']}") String v1User;
private @Value("#{v1Properties['v1.password']}") String v1Password;

@Bean
V1Config v1Config() {
    V1Config v1Config = new V1Config();
    v1Config.setDataUrl(dataUrl);
    v1Config.setMetaUrl(metaUrl);
    v1Config.setUserId(v1User);
    v1Config.setPassword(v1Password);
    return v1Config;
}

@Bean
ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return resolver;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this out,

```
@ImportResource("classpath:properties-config.xml")
```